# Skip pundit scope on one controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, pundit

I want to skip the **policy_scope** requirement fro Pundit on one controller (home). I have tried this:

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Pundit
  after_action :verify_authorized, :except => :index, unless: :devise_controller?
  after_action :verify_policy_scoped, :only => :index, unless: controller.controller_name == "home"
 end

 class HomeController < ApplicationController
   def index
     redirect_to (new_user_session_path) unless user_signed_in?
     if user_signed_in?
       @user=current_user
     end
    end
  end
```

But I don't think the controller is defined yet or something? Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

I accomplished this by adding a skip_after_action to the home controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  skip_after_action :verify_policy_scoped, :only => :index
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Since version 1.0.0 you can use `skip_policy_scope` in a controller action.